# Proper way to close RethinkDB changes() running in thread?

Tags: rethinkdb, watch

We have a call to `changes()` running in a thread so we can monitor for changes to a table while doing other processing. When our process wants to close, the thread doesn't close and keeps the process running. Closing the connection with `noreply_wait` ([see here](https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/close/)) makes it happen because causes an error, so is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would need a bit more info to be of assistance.
What type of environment are you connecting to the rethink server in?
What is launching the process that you need to monitor changes during and what type of events does that process emit upon completion?

Im going to assume your working in a node.js environment, unless told otherwise

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
r.table('yourTable').filter(function(row) {
    return row('yourProperty').eq('trueVal');
})
.changes()
.run(rethinkConnection, function(err, cursor) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        const doingThings = spawn('command', ['option1', 'option2']);
        doingThings.on('exit', function() {
            cursor.close();
        });
        cursor.each(function(err, row) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // do thing with changefeed row here
            }
        });
    }
});
```